# DOMDocument buscar tag aninhada XML

Tags: php, xml, php-domdocument

Estou buscando os dados do XML abaixo para salvar em variáveis PHP para futuro tratamento. O trecho do XML abaixo é o que estou trabalhando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro do "notas_fiscais", consegui extrair corretamente os dados até a tag "nome". Quando chego na "cliente" não consigo extrair corretamente, os dados ficam incoerentes. Estou usando o método abaixo:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

//COMO É XML (COM A CHAVE) ABRE DIRETO COMO DOMDocument
$filename = "http://localhost/arq.xml";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load( $filename);
    ## lets read the NF block (NIVEL 1)
    $records = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "nota_fiscal" );
    foreach( $records as $record ) { // NIVEL NF
        ## parse the ID
        $id = $record->getElementsByTagName( "id" );
        $id = $id->item(0)->nodeValue;
        ## parse the TIPO
        $tipo = $record->getElementsByTagName( "tipo" );
        $tipo = $tipo->item(0)->nodeValue;
        ## parse the SERIE
        $serie = $record->getElementsByTagName( "serie" );
        $serie = $serie->item(0)->nodeValue;
        ## parse NUMERO
        $numero = $record->getElementsByTagname( "numero" );
        $numero = $numero->item(0)->nodeValue;
        ## parse DATA_EMISSAO
        $data_emissao = $record->getElementsByTagname( "data_emissao" );
        $data_emissao = $data_emissao->item(0)->nodeValue;
        ## parse NOME
        $nome = $record->getElementsByTagname( "nome" );
        $nome = $nome->item(0)->nodeValue;


           ## lets read the CLIENTE block (NIVEL 2)
           $records_2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "cliente" );
           foreach( $records_2 as $record_2 ) { // NIVEL CLIENTE
                ## parse the NOME
                $nome_2 = $record_2->getElementsByTagName( "nome" );
                $nome_2 = $nome_2->item(0)->nodeValue;         
                ## parse the TIPO_PESSOA
                $tp_pessoa_2 = $record_2->getElementsByTagName( "tipo_pessoa" );
                $tp_pessoa_2 = $tp_pessoa_2->item(0)->nodeValue;    
                ## parse the CPF_CNPJ
                $cpf_cnpj_2 = $record_2->getElementsByTagName( "cpf_cnpj" );
                $cpf_cnpj_2 = $cpf_cnpj_2->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Fiz abrindo um segundo loop dentro do primeiro, mas acredito que não é a forma correta. Como poderia proceder?

EDIT:
Se faço da forma abaixo, ele traz todos valores abaixo da tag "cliente", mas não consigo separar:

```
$nome_2 = $record->getElementsByTagname( "cliente" );       
$nome_2 = $nome_2->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Para pegar os dados do cliente seria assim:

```
foreach( $records as $record ) { // NIVEL NF
        ## parse the ID
        $id = $record->getElementsByTagName( "id" );
        $id = $id->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //código emitido

        //Faria assim pra pegar os dados do cliente
        $xpathCliente = new DOMXpath($doc);
        $nome = $xpathCliente->query('cliente/nome', $record)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $tipoPessoa = $xpathCliente->query('cliente/tipo_pessoa', $record)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        //E assim por diante
}
```

Mais sobre a sintaxe do XPath [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

Um testador online de XPath [aqui](http://xpather.com/GzyYMIie).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas nesse caso não me atende, pois preciso pegar todas informações além do nome. E o XML está montando dessa forma, não consigo alterar a forma de extrair os dados...

Comment: Não seria só adicionar a chamada para as outras propriedades: cliente[nome], cliente[tipo_pessoa] e assim por diante?

Comment: Como assim? pode exemplificar?

Comment: algo assim ?       
        $nome_2 = $record->getElementsByTagname( "cliente[nome]" );
        $nome_2 = $nome_2->item(0)->nodeValue;

Comment: Editei a resposta principal pra ver se fica mais claro.

Comment: Consegui arrumar, vou aceitar tua resposta, só edita que mudei na query: $xpathPesquisa->query('cliente/nome', $record)->item(0)->nodeValue;